# Pie chart legend position

Tags: c#, charts

I am making a pie chart. In the chart, the legends comes at the bottom of the chart by default. I want to put the legends in the side of the pie chart so that all the legends will visible. Here is the code:

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
Chart1.Series["Series1"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder"; //Emboss,Cylinder,LightToDark,Wedge,Default
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
Chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

Chart1.DataSource = dt;
Chart1.Series["TBMTBRRecipeSeries"].XValueMember = "Code";
Chart1.Series["TBMTBRRecipeSeries"].YValueMembers = "number";
Chart1.DataBind();
```

How can I put the legend at the side of the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `Docking` property. Set that as `Right` and `IsDockedInsideChartArea` as true.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58993917/11697039 any help thanks @danish