# Google Pie Chart Change Text Alignment

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, google-pie-chart

Here is my report,

[image]

How to change my bottom value one by one instead of scroll.

```
 var options = {
                legend:'bottom',
                is3D: true
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to allow multiple lines on the legend,
you must use legend position --> `'top'`
then you can increase the number of --> `maxLines`

```
legend: {
  position: 'top',
  maxLines: 3
},
```

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options)...

> `legend.maxLines` - Maximum number of lines in the legend. Set this to a number greater than one to add lines to your legend. This option works only when `legend.position` is `'top'`.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['category', 'value'],
    ['Category 1', 34],
    ['Category 2', 18.7],
    ['Category 3', 18.6],
    ['Category 4', 18.6],
    ['Category 5', 10]
  ]);

  var pie = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart-pie'));
  pie.draw(data, {
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      maxLines: 3
    },
    height: 400,
    is3D: true,
    width: 400
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart-pie"></div>
```

Comment: How to align bottom and one by one, above shown left 3 & right 2. How to align bottom one by one. Thanks. @WhiteHat

Comment: When aligned to the bottom, the legend can only have one row, instead of multiple rows as when aligned to the top. As such, the chart would have to be wide enough to allow room for all the labels. You could also reduce the legend's font size to create more room.